# Swift: Passing same type objects in function parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I have several view controllers that I want to pass into the initialiser of a navigation class here is that init method below...

```
    init(frame: CGRect, gameScene: GameSCNScene, gameViewController: anyObject) {
    // Code
    }
```

I made the third parameter anyObject because it will receive the different view controller classes depending on which viewController calls it at the time. Problem is gameViewController is nil. If I change anyObject to a specific viewController class name ie GameViewController, then it works.

I thought perhaps I could change it to UIViewController since all my view controllers derive from UIViewController but that doesnt work either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you calling this `init` method?

Comment: What is your parent type Controller, like UIViewController you can change that anyobject to ParentViewController type.

Comment: From inside each view Controller, this is from one of those controllers `        navBar = NavigationBar(frame: rect, gameScene: game1Scene, gameViewController: self)`

Comment: All my controllers are just new files from UIViewController that will call this method to create a new Navigation object inside itself. `        navBar = NavigationBar(frame: rect, gameScene: game1Scene, gameViewController: self)`